# C# Extending base class from plugin without replicating constructor arguments

Tags: c#, plugins, dependency-injection

I'm building an application with plugin support. I have a core part of the functionality that may or may not can be extended by plugins. So basic idea looks like this:

```cs
interface IFoo {
   void PerformFoo();
}

class CoreFoo {
    CoreFoo(Dependency1 dep1, [SomeDependencyInjectionAttribute] Dependency2 dep2) {
        // assign to fields
    }

    void PerformFoo() {
        this.Bar();
        // other actions
    }

    protected virtual void Bar() {
        // Do bar
    }    
}

class PluginFoo : CoreFoo {
    PluginFoo(Dependency1 dep1, [SomeDependencyInjectionAttribute] Dependency2 dep2, PluginDependency dep3) 
        : base(dep1, dep2) 
    { /* assign to fields */ }

    protected override void Bar() {
        // Do changed bar
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having that `PluginFoo` is tightly coupled with `CoreFoo` constructor and will have to replicate all arguments to inject them properly. So any change of `CoreFoo` constructor will break compatibility `PluginFoo`. How can this be avoided?

I can think of a semi-bad solution to inject dependencies as some `DependencyBundle` class which I can change without touching `PluginFoo` class, like so:

```cs
class FooDependencyBundle {
    FooDependencyBundle(Dependency1 dep1, [SomeDependencyInjectionAttribute] Dependency2 dep2) {
        // assign to properties
    }
}

class CoreFoo {
    CoreFoo(FooDependencyBundle deps) {
        // assign to fields
    }

    // ... implementation  
}
```

But it feels kinda wrong. Are there any better ones?

Comment: By inheriting from a class, by definition you are creating a tight coupling. The same argument could be said for `protected virtual void Bar()`; if that was to change, all derived classes would have to be changed.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I suppose, you're correct. I meant that I want to have coupling that is less tight. :) So it will be more resilient to base class changes.

Comment: This isn't going to be possible. Through inheritance,`PluginFoo` **is a** `CoreFoo`, and by declaring the constructor on `CoreFoo` you are stating that it needs a `Dependancy1` and `Dependancy2`, so therefore `PluginFoo` must also depend on these. If you really do want to reduce coupling, then prefer composition over inheritance, unless you need `PluginFoo` to be used as a `CoreFoo`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Well, yes `PluginFoo` should be used as `CoreFoo`. 

When using `DependencyBundle` I can avoid changing `PluginFoo`, so it will stay compatible. I'm not sure about binary compatibility, but at least no code changes are required. So it's kinda achievable.

If I will use composition, `PluginFoo` will be extremely sensitive to every `CoreFoo` change, so I would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

U can create something like toolbox service and inject this in Core constructor. Then if u want add something new in Core functionality u add dependency in toolbox and U dont must change anything in Core constructor or plugins class.

```
class CoreFoo {
    CoreFoo([SomeDependencyInjectionAttribute] DependencyToolboxService service) {
        // assign to fields
    }

    void PerformFoo() {
        this.Bar();
        // other actions
    }

    protected virtual void Bar() {
        // Do bar
    }    
}

class PluginFoo : CoreFoo {
    PluginFoo([SomeDependencyInjectionAttribute] DependencyToolboxService service, PluginDependency dep3) 
        : base(service) 
    { /* assign to fields */ }

    protected override void Bar() {
        // Do changed bar
    }
}
```

Toolbox service can  looks like

```
public class DependencyToolbox : IToolbox
{
     public readonly Dependency Dependency1;

     public DependencyToolbox(Dependency dependency1, //Other services,dependencies//)
     {
         Dependency1 = dependency1;
     }
}
```

Comment: Well, that is my default solution, I was even mentioning it in the original question. I'm interested if there are some alternatives.

Comment: Ok i have not notice `DependencyBundle` solution in your question.

Comment: U can use `Property injection` instead of `Method injection` but this is little ugly solution